# How to handle errors raised in an imported python package code?

Tags: python-3.x, exception

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\farha\Desktop\VoicebotRuuh_6_langs_Modified - Copy\chatbot.py", line 188, in 
>       exec()
>     File "C:\Users\farha\Desktop\VoicebotRuuh_6_langs_Modified - Copy\chatbot.py", line 121, in exec
>       result = r.recognize_google(audio)
>     File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition__init__.py", line 859, in recognize_google
>       if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
>   speech_recognition.UnknownValueError

This is what I get when I run 'python chatbot.py'
There is an error raised in **init**.py file which is a file in the python package called speech_recognition, which is imported into chatbot.py.
Following is a snippet of chatbot.py based on this problem.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
try:
    audio = r.record(source, duration = 5)
    #print("Done")
except:
    exec()
```

- I guess this is not working because the error is raised in the imported python package file but not in the main file (chatbot.py)
- How do I handle this error?

Comment: In practice what is the question? How to handle errors when importing modules or how to solve your specific issue?

Comment: you got any solution for this `r.recognize_google(audio)` ??? i got the same error too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> use the error as an exception!

```
  import speech_recognition as sr
    try:
        audio = r.record(source, duration = 5)
        #print("Done")
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        exec()
```

Comment: please don't use blockquotes for regular text.